# I want to get data from an data array and in my code .map thorough error while execute successfully

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ProductItem from '../components/ProductItem/ProductItem';


class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.renderProductItems =this.renderProductItems.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(product){
        this.props.handleAddToCart(product)
    }
    renderProductItems(product){
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6" key={product.id}>
            <ProductItem>
                product={product}
                handleClick={this.handleClick}
            </ProductItem>
            </div>
        );
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.product.map(this.props.renderProductItems)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

Comment: And the problem? Please choose a concise title for your question and try to explain what is the problem you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to map over an array and pass the data to a method, you can use this

```
this.props.product.map((item) => this.renderProductItems(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `this.props.renderProductItems` inside map function call, that's the issue.

This function is not passed as props, rather defined inside class. You should access it using `this.renderProductItems`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see `renderProductItems` is not a prop from a parent component.

So just like Rahul said, the first obvious issue is that you are using `this.props.renderProductItems` instead of `this.renderProductItems` just the way you are using `this.handleClick`correctly.

Goodluck